# Creating a new column from the entries from value_count() in a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there any way to create a new column to the a dataframe that includes the values from the column contributor_occupation?

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv(f'C:/Users/Miles/Downloads/schedule_a-2024-03-27T21 32 51.csv')
list = []
old_df = dataframe[dataframe['entity_type'] == 'IND']
df = old_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['contributor_name'], keep='first')
new_df = df['contributor_occupation'].value_counts(ascending = False).head(25)
a_df = new_df.to_frame()
print(new_df)
```

Ideally my dataframe would look like this

```
contributor_occupation   count    
RETIRED                 11891
CEO                       175
OWNER                     167
PRESIDENT                 155
ATTORNEY                  109
CONSULTANT                 96
PHYSICIAN                  92
SALES                      91
ENGINEER                   77
EXECUTIVE                  69
REAL ESTATE                66
MANAGER                    59
FARMER                     57
HOMEMAKER                  47
REALTOR                    44
RN                         42
INVESTOR                   40
CHAIRMAN                   39
CONTRACTOR                 38
BUSINESS OWNER             37
LAWYER                     36
CPA                        35
SELF                       34
SELF EMPLOYED              27
TRUCK DRIVER               25
```

But my program creates a dataframe with only the 'count column'

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want a new column in the original frame, then either use `groupby.transform` ot `map` the output of `value_counts`.

Comment: If this is not what you want, please be explicit, provide a [mre] of the input (we can't access your file) and the exact matching expected output.